# Call a function in another script when executing using 'Run With PowerShell'

Tags: function, powershell

I have functions in a 'library' file to be called from my 'worker' script.

**Library File**

```
function ShowMessage($AValue)
{
  $a = new-object -comobject wscript.shell
  $b = $a.popup( $AValue )
}
```

**Worker File**

```
. {c:\scratch\b.ps1}

ShowMessage "Hello"
```

Running the 'worker' script works fine when in the PowerShell IDE but when I right-click the worker file and choose 'Run with PowerShell' it cannot find the function 'ShowMessage'. Both files are in the same folder. What might be happening?

Comment: Also note that invoking the script using `&`, eg. `& "c:\scratch\b.ps1"` doesn't import the functions.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

In the worker file change to this:

```
. "c:\scratch\b.ps1"

ShowMessage "Hello"
```

As @RoiDanton mentioned below:

> Attention when using relative pathing: Don't forget to prepend a dot
>   before the path . ".\b.ps1".

The first dot is an operator used to modify the scope and in that context it has nothing to do with paths. See [Dot Source Notation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes?view=powershell-6).

Comment: Attention when using relative pathing: Don't forget to prepend a dot before the path `. ".\b.ps1"`. Being very new to psh, I didn't know that the first dot is an operator to modify the scope and in that context has nothing to do with paths. See [Dot Source Notation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes).

Comment: @RoiDanton you're great Roi... thanks for adding this comment... this is what I was searching for, that is, how to call a function from another script that's inside the same folder\path using relative path.

Comment: The relative pathing not working for me. I'm using PowerShell 5.1, does this have anything to do with it?

Answer (score 19):

In your worker file, dot-source the library file, this will load all content (functions, variables, etc) to the global scope, and then you'll be able to call functions from the library file.

```
=================== Worker file ==========================
# dot-source library script
# notice that you need to have a space 
# between the dot and the path of the script
. c:\library.ps1

ShowMessage -AValue Hello
=================== End Worker file ======================
```

Comment: It's safer to enclose path in quotes, in case there will be space, like Program Files

Comment: Agree, but this path has no spaces :). I tend to remove quotes when they are not necessary.

Comment: Good answer, but it's the _current_ scope that "dot-sourcing" a file causes it to run in, which may or may not be the _global_ scope.